# Skype for business web sdk integration for public facing site

Tags: azure-active-directory, skype-for-business, skypedeveloper

We have a public facing website to capture leads and we are trying to use Skype for busines web sdk for communication aspect (audio, video, chat and etc.). In order to deploy the SFB conversation control on the page we have to Sign in with office 365 credentials to authenticate using azure active directory, which is not we want in a public facing site where anonymouns users will visit.

A lot of visitors can visit the website at the same time and chat with available person. How will we distinguish the chat history of each visitor from others if they chat with only one person.

Also we have plan for creating multiple sub-domains sites and distribute among our partners. Can we use same application(clientId/ApplicationId) registered on azure portal for authentication on partners websites or we have to create a new application for each one.

Comment: Did you get any Solution?

Comment: @AnjireddyVangala: Not yet, we put it on hold as we get stuck.